# Hide elements without knowing complete id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like below

```
<table id="categoriesTable">

 <tr id=row_id1_dynamicdata> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>..</td>
 </tr>

<tr id=row_id2_dynamicdata> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>..</td>
</tr>

<tr id=row_id3_dynamicdata> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>..</td>
</tr>

<tr id=row_id4_dynamicdata> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>..</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I want to hide all rows except row whose id contains id4. I won't have full id.
I came up with below jQuery code, but as I don't have full id, it doesn't work.

```
var idValue = document.getElementById(someElement);
$('#categoreisTable').find('tr').not($('#row_' +idValue)).hide();
```

How to filter with only half the id?

Comment: What exactly is half id?

Comment: So what will be pre-fix ID or half I D?

Comment: example id=row_catergory1_subCategory1  . I know value till row_category1 . Nick suggested to use Attribute starts with .  I am testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ["Attribute starts with"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to find the rows which don't match the one with the specified `idValue`. For example:

```js
$('#someElement').on('change', function() {
  var idValue = this.value;
  $('#categoriesTable')
    .find('tr')
    .show()    // not needed if you only want to hide
    .not('[id^="row_id' + idValue + '_"]')
    .hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="categoriesTable">

  <tr id=row_id1_dynamicdata>
    <td>.1..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>


  <tr id=row_id2_dynamicdata>
    <td>.2..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id=row_id3_dynamicdata>
    <td>.3..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id=row_id4_dynamicdata>
    <td>.4..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="text" id="someElement" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on the `tr` element and then run a loop to only show rows that include **id4** in their id.

Run the snippet below:

```js
var idValue = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

for (i = 0; i < idValue.length; i++) {
  if (idValue[i].id.includes("id4")) {
      idValue[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      idValue[i].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
```

```html
<table id="categoriesTable">

  <tr id=row_id1_dynamicdata>
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>


  <tr id=row_id2_dynamicdata>
    <td>row2</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id=row_id3_dynamicdata>
    <td>row3</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id=row_id4_dynamicdata>
    <td>row 4</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr id=anotherrow_id4_dynamicdata>
    <td>another row with  id4</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementsByTagName to get all id contain id4.

Then, just to hide them.

```
let ElementArray = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), element => element.id.match('id4'));
let idArray = ElementArray.forEach(element => document.getElementById(element.id).style.display="none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
$('#categoriesTable tr').not('[id^="row_id4_"]').hide();
```